# Regex to append date to a strings with file extension and also without file extensions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings where I need to append date to a strings with file extension and also without file extensions.

For example

1. Fruits
2. Fruits.doc
3. Fruits.docx
4. Fruits.Apple.docx

The expected result is

1. Fruits_18-9-2020
2. Fruits_18-9-2020.doc
3. Fruits_18-9-2020.docx
4. Fruits.Apple_18-9-2020.docx

I tried this

```
  var str = 'Fruits.txt'; 
  var txt = str.replace(/$/i,"_123");
```

But it gives me Fruits.txt_123 which is incorrect

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex instead :

```
str.replace(/(?=\.[^\.]+$)|(?<=^[^\.]+$)/, "_123");
```

Test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H4T98Z/1)!

Explanations:

- the `|` separates the cases where there is an extension (like .doc, left part: `(?=\.[^\.]+$)`) or no extension (right part: `(?<=^[^\.]+$)`).
- With extension: get the position of the last dot before the end, and insert the additional string before the match (using lookahead).
- Without extension: if there is no dot in the whole string before the end, just insert the text at the end (using a lookbehind).